# Android- The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) implementation in Retrofit library?

Tags: android, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

How should I use the `Retrofit` library in my `Android` project to follow the `SRP` principles (`The Single Responsibility Principle` in `SOLID` principles)?

**EDIT 1**

I find out an article which introduces `SOLID` principles in Android applications:

- [Android Development: the SOLID Principles](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-development-the-solid-principles-3b5779b105d2)

So, as the link describes, there are some considerations about implementing `SOLID` principles in Android application.

**Edit 2: I limited the question to be more specific in SRP principles.**

Comment: there is nothing specific SOLID principle for Android, it used same way in android as it is used in java.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay I've updated my post. there is an article around that!

Comment: Your question is still way too broad.

Comment: @Steven But I've limited that as possible. Can I ask you how do you suggest editing this question, please?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: @Steven Hi Steven. Thanks for letting me know.